# useradd on CentOS with home directory and sudo privileges

Tags: centos, sudo, privileges, useradd, asterisk

There are so many variants to `adduser` or `useradd` -- which is correct?

On `CentOS release 5.11 (Final)` I'm using `adduser --create-home  baz` but somewhat prefer the way Ubuntu asks extraneous questions about contact information.  On [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/85740/45156), just `adduser desired_user_name sudo` which is easier to remember -- at least for me.

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-centos-quickstart) says to use `adduser` and `usermod`:

> Use the usermod command to add the user to the wheel group.
>
> ```
> usermod -aG wheel username
> ```
>
> By default, on CentOS, members of the wheel group have sudo
>   privileges.

Just handled differently?

(This is on Elastix 2.5 (asterisk) running on CentOS.)

Comment: As an aside, useradd is the POSIX way of adding users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-G`

For [CentOS Doc](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-users-add.html)

> ```
> -G<group-list>    
>
>        List of additional (other than default) group names or group 
>        numbers, separated by commas, of which the user is a member. The
>        groups must exist prior to being specified here.
> ```

so you can do this with

```
useradd username -d <customer_home_dir_path> -G <group_names>
```